# Piping with Moreutils ts

Tags: command-line, sed, pipe

I have an incoming stream at a serial port, with new lines appearing about once per second

```
wren@Raven:~$ cat /dev/ttyUSB0

A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00

A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00

A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00

A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00

A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00
```

I want to strip blank lines and timestamp the remainder.

sed will cull blank lines and add a timestamp, but I can't make the timestamp update, it just reports the time it was invoked:

```
wren@Raven:~$ cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | sed -e '/^$/d' -e "s/$/`date +\,%F\,%T`/"
A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00,2014-05-14,09:44:42
A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00,2014-05-14,09:44:42
A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00,2014-05-14,09:44:42
A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00,2014-05-14,09:44:42
A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00,2014-05-14,09:44:42
A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00,2014-05-14,09:44:42
A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00,2014-05-14,09:44:42
^C
```

I've found ts, part of Moreutils, and can pipe into it to get an updating timestamp.

```
wren@Raven:~$ cat /dev/ttyUSB0 |  ts
May 14 09:49:26 A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00
May 14 09:49:26
May 14 09:49:27 A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00
^C
```

However, I can't properly combine ts with sed.

This, which looks like it should do what I want, produces no output at all

```
wren@Raven:~$ cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | sed -e '/^$/d' | ts
^C
wren@Raven:~$
```

However reversing the order of the pipes does produce an output, but of course doesn't strip lines which are no longer blank. Other substitutions work fine, so I know the pipe to sed is working.

```
wren@Raven:~$ cat /dev/ttyUSB0 |  ts | sed -e '/^$/d'
May 14 10:07:25 A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00
May 14 10:07:25
May 14 10:07:26 A_Sensor1,B_22.00,C_50.00
May 14 10:07:26
^C
```

So I'm a bit baffled.  I can presumably make sed remove the unwanted lines, but timestamping them prior to removal must be the wrong approach.

I would appreciate an explanation and some help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer the question directly, `sed` is buffering and that's the sole problem.
You can fix this by telling it not to buffer with its `-u`/`--unbuffered` flag:

```
sed -u '/^$/d' /dev/ttyUSB0 | ts
```

With a test harness (but you'll need to run it for proof):

```
$ (echo -e 'banana\n\n'; sleep 2; echo 'cheese') | sed -u '/^$/d' | ts
May 14 11:26:05 banana
May 14 11:26:07 cheese
```

You can run into similar predicaments with other stream editors. They seemingly all want to buffer a little bit. They all have workarounds though. Here are a bunch of commands I've tested:

```
... | mawk -W interactive '/./' | ts
... | gawk '/./ { print $0; fflush(); }' | ts
... | grep --line-buffered '.' | ts
... | perl -n -e 'print if /./' | ts
```

---

Another idea is to just let `gawk` handle it. It can filter for non-empty lines and [do the date-printing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21620/12870) for you (thanks to SO's [Kieron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588/kieron)):

```
awk '/./ { print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }' /dev/ttyUSB0
```

That flushes straight after lines come in. `gawk` is especially helpful here if you want to do *other* things... If you want to check that the fourth column of output (pre-`ts`) matches a regex, you can (eg `$4~/\d{4}/`). Awk (and its variants) are very flexible for stream processing.

Another test harness:

```
$ gawk '/./ { print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }' <(
      echo -e 'banana\n\n';
      sleep 2;
      echo 'cheese'
  )
2014-05-14 11:13:59 banana
2014-05-14 11:14:01 cheese
```

Comment: +1 for `sed -u`. It is a block-buffering vs. line-buffering issue.

Comment: @Oli sed -u also works perfectly when piped into ts, so I'll read up about buffering. I'm no longer baffled, many thanks.

Comment: awk is particularly well suited for things like this. awk code is generally a lot less dense and much more readable than sed and you can throw in as many print statements as you want to view partial results while debugging. You can put a whole awk program into a here document to avoid using a separate file and if you put quotes around the here document terminator string, then bash will ignore all the embedded tokens it would normally try to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

bash can handle this in a `while read` loop

```
(echo -e 'banana\n\n'; sleep 2; echo 'cheese') | 
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    [[ $line ]] && echo "$(date "+%F %T") line"
done
```

```
2014-05-14 06:34:06 banana
2014-05-14 06:34:08 cheese
```

You can remove lines with only whitespace with a tricky parameter expansion: remove all leading whitespace and see if the line is empty:

```
shopt -s extglob

(echo -e '  banana\n\t\n'; sleep 2; echo 'cheese') |
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ "${line/#+([[:blank:]])/}" ]] && echo "$(date "+%F %T") $line"
done
```

Comment: I tried a variety of approaches like that, none of them worked. I can't get your code to work either. Using echo or cat to send /dev/ttyUSB0 to the while loop just results in a single line of output : 2014-05-14 12:23:32 line

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way, but try `tail -f /dev/ttyUSB0` instead of cat or echo. It will keep running. I didn't know how to test this on my system.

Comment: tail -f /dev/ttyUSB0 gives no output, with or without the while loop. tvm for your comments.